# Linear transformation / Polynomial Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

$T:P_{3}\rightarrow P_{3}$ defined by $T(p(t))=tp'(t)+p(0)$ is a linear transformation.

Determine whether $T$ is invertible.

If yes, find $T^{-1}(q(t))$, where $q(t)$ is a polynomial of degree at most three.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. I (we) hope you stick around. :) You might benefit from reading [how to ask](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). It will help you with your future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Just take a polynomial $p \in P_3$, say $p(X) = aX^3 + bX^2 + cX + d$ and compute $q := T(p)$. Then check whether you can invert the transformation of the coefficients.

Comment: Thanks martini. What does the term $p(0)$ mean?

Comment: $p(0)$ is the value of $p$ at $t=0$, if for example $p(t) = t^2 + 3t + 1$, then $p(0) = 0^2 + 3\cdot 0 + 1 = 1$.

Comment: I see! Thank you so much :-)

Comment: One last thing... I have got that if $p(t)=at^3+bt^2+ct+d$, then $T(p(t))=3at^3+2bt^2+ct+d$. I understand that I can write the inverse of $T$ as a matrix <1/3, 1/2, 1, 1>, but how to put that into a nice form like $p(t)$ is in?